# bert-as-service maximum sequence length

Tags: nlp, sequence, bert

I installed bert-as-service ([bert-as-service github repo](https://github.com/hanxiao/bert-as-service)) and tried encoding some sentences in Japanese on the `multi_cased_L-12_H-768_A-12` model.  It seems to work as I am getting vectors of length 768 per word but `np.shape()` shows this for each sentence:

```
np.shape(vec_j[0]): (25, 768)
np.shape(vec_j[1]): (25, 768)
np.shape(vec_j[2]): (25, 768)
np.shape(vec_j[3]): (25, 768)
np.shape(vec_j[4]): (25, 768)
type: <class 'numpy.ndarray'>
```

My sentences are short so there is quite a bit of padding with 0's.  Still, I am unsure why this model seems to have a maximum sequence length of 25 rather than the 512 mentioned here:  [Bert documentation section on tokenization](https://github.com/google-research/bert/blob/master/README.md)

> "Truncate to the maximum sequence length. (You can use up to 512, but
>   you probably want to use shorter if possible for memory and speed
>   reasons.)"

Comment: Hi @mLstudent33, I am using Bert-as-service as well, but I only get (1, 768) size vector for each sentence. Would you mind sharing your code snippet, say on Github or with me via email? Thanks!

Comment: Hi can you look through my repos?  My github username is nyck33.

Comment: Thanks. But I see you have 50 repos. Which one should I look into?

Comment: It says I used bert-as-service in the question with a link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default setting for `max_seq_len` is 25 as seen here under heading Server API:  [bert-as-service readme](https://github.com/hanxiao/bert-as-service#q-how-can-i-get-word-embedding-instead-of-sentence-embedding)

There is an open issue regarding this on the Github repo here and the creator seems to be implementing a feature:  [bert-as-service issues](https://github.com/hanxiao/bert-as-service/issues/233)